# Stream parameter is always null

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I am sending post request from my client (ASP.NET MVC) to a webapi service, however, the webapi service controller needs a `Stream` parameter which is always `null`.

#### Request from ASP.NET MVC app:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    Token token = GetToken();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.TokenType, token.AccessToken);
    var content = new StreamContent(stream);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "keliaStream" };
    var res = client.PostAsync(GetSdcUri(), content).Result;
}
```

#### WebApi Controller:

```
// POST: api/Publication
[HttpPost]
[Route("whatever-route")]
[RequireHttps]
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GenerateSDCFromTBox([FromBody]Stream keliaStream)
{
    // whatever
}
```

`keliaStream` is always null, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `this.Request.InputStream` instead or accepting it as an action method parameter?

Comment: @Dai : My controll inherits from `ApiController` so I don't have `Request.InputStream`, instead I have `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`. But if I try to use it, it throws an error : `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream = 'HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'`

Comment: `ApiController` is `System.Web.Http` (Web API) which is a separate stack from ASP.NET MVC (which is `System.Web.Mvc`) - I think that's part of your problem (don't mix MVC and Web API when you're not using ASP.NET Core).

Comment: @Dai : My web application is ASP.NET MVC and I have to request an existing webservice which is WebAPI. I don't really have a choice here :-/

Comment: Making requests to an another webservice that uses ASP.NET Web API does not require you to use Web API at all - or even C#/.NET.

Comment: you need to add stream as body not headers in MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, I've been able to find a solution.
In case anyone struggles with the same problem here is my solution :

#### Client (ASP.NET MVC) :

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    Token token = GetToken();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token.TokenType, token.AccessToken);
    var content = new StreamContent(stream);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var res = client.PostAsync(GetSdcUri(), content).Result;
}
```

#### SERVEUR (WebApi) :

```
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GenerateSDCFromTBox()
{
    Stream stream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    // return do what ever with stream
}
```